# How can I change a UITabBarItem title to the title from another UITabBarItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I want to change the title of UITabBarItem 1 to that of UITabBarItem 4.

Both are in the same UITabBarController.

How do I go about changing these titles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSArray * items = tabBar.items ;
((UITabBarItem*)[ items objectAtIndex:0 ]).title = 
    ((UITabBarItem*)[ items objectAtIndex:3 ]).title
```